# Postgres Foreign Key Chain

Tags: sql, postgresql

Postgres 9.4

I want to create a foreign key restraint that links three tables rather than two:

```
Components: workout_id
Results: component_id
```

I want to make sure `workout_id` can not be changed in a `component` if there are any `results` that reference that `component`.

Comment: Please make clear what problems or errors you encountered. Or is it just `on delete restrict` ?

Comment: I want the database to refuse to change workout_id in a component record if there exists any result which has a reference to that component record.

Comment: I think it'd help if you sketched the table structure out. Also, why?

Answer (score 0):

You can't create Foreign Keys with three tables, but you can create two Foreign Keys with two tables.

If you have tables A, B, and C with A being a constraint for B, and a constraint for C

Create two FK: A to B and A to C